# unicode-math loads graphicx? Why?

Tags: graphics, unicode-math

It seems, looking @ the console, that the unicode-math package for XeTeX & LuaTeX loads graphic.sty.  Why?  I guess that saves me 1 line of code in the preamble.  Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

Some lines in console (after running LuaTeX):

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty
```

Comment: It doesn't on my machine. Note that TeX Live 2016 is obsolete.

Comment: It doesn't do it here (neither in tl16 nor in newer versions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `graphicx` package is loaded by `xunicode`, which used to be loaded by `fontspec`, but isn't any longer from a couple of years, unless the `EU1` encoding is required.

The `xunicode` package uses `\scalebox` for some of its macros.

Comment: From (a very old) `xunicode.sty`: `% faking right tone bars from left ones
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\def\TIPAfakertonebar#1{{\TIPAreversedata#1!!@!!%
 \reflectbox{\expandafter\TIPAfakertonebari\expandafter{\TIPAtonedata}}}}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It's still in the current version of `xunicode.sty`.

Comment: Fixed it: Upgraded to TeX Live 2018, still loads fontspec, but not xunicode, nor graphics/x.